# Who are my "connections" on Monster.com?

Tags: monster.com

I have a resume on [Monster](http://monster.com). To avoid many unnecessary calls, I decided restrict who can see my contact information. In the privacy settings, I can see the option **Limited**:

[image: privacy settings]

Then I see that my contact information is visible only to my 1st Degree Connections:

[image: 1st Degree connections]

What is the Monster network? On Monster's FAQ page, I read:

> When we talk about the Monster network, we mean the websites and
>   applications owned or controlled by Monster Worldwide, Inc. These
>   include Monster's job search websites, the Monster Communities,
>   Fastweb.com, Military.com, and other apps published by Monster, and
>   any other property that we create or acquire. Information may be
>   shared among any of the sites or applications in the Monster network,
>   but it will always be used as described in the privacy policy of the
>   site or application where it was collected. You should read the
>   privacy policy carefully to understand how it applies to information
>   collected on the site or application you are using.

So, my contact information should be visible only to my 1st Degree Connections, but I still receive a lot of calls from recruiters, apparently they see this information.

Who are my connections ... everybody?

And what is difference between **Visible** and **Limited** options?